# Sencha Touch 2 + PhoneGap + iPad: Video with base64 encoded data: "The Operation could not be completed"

Tags: javascript, android, ios, html, sencha-touch-2

My application (wrapped in PhoneGap) runs both online and offline mode. I store images and videos encoded in base64 in localstorage.
When I debug this on browser it runs just fine, but on iPad it shouts out "The operation could not be completed" in a javascript promt.

I've tried placing the video with pure html tag and tru Ext.Video.

I'm missing anything here? Thanks

```
newhtml += "<video width='320' height='240' controls='controls'> <source src='data:video/mp4;base64,"+tmpStore.getAt(i).data.myPages[j].myProducts[k].myItens[0].fileData+"'  /></video>";
```

Update:

Tested in iPad and Android 3.0 native browsers and the result is the same "The operation...".
Tested with and without autoplay and controllers (in the video/source tags).

Comment: Check by posting it on Sencha Touch forum ..

Comment: I did it: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?198958-iPad-Video-with-base64-encoded-data-quot-The-Operation-could-not-be-completed-quot&p=791740#post791740

Comment: seems that it's badly ignored...

Comment: Yes, they want to sell their support services :D

Comment: At least you're missing the closing tag for video element.

Comment: That was copy-paste error, the tags are ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PhoneGap does not recognise **video** tag.

Comment: Thank you. Can you link any source of that info please?

Comment: http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.com/2012/02/android-issues-all-phonegap-developers.html?m=1

Comment: Thank you. So as you source explains video tag is no supported in a WebView (not PhoneGap itself). That would be a Google's/Apple's problem, I'll dig more into this and reply later.

Comment: Calmdown, I though you were just a troll. I'll be digging this, and come back later. Thanks

Comment: This is Android only, though. It should work just fine on iOS. I have done it many times before. Perhaps it is because the video is in localStorage?

Comment: @rdougan  ios and android both use the same webkit browser.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the TYPE attribute:  `type="video/mp4"` on the `source` element.

And for some reason on Android it starts working when you make it: `src='data:video/mp4;base64,AAAA'` [Do not ask why AAAA, I don't know. Found it somewhere and it helped me]

Hope this helps someone.